# Karate: Is there a way of getting JSON object keys length from an Examples variable?

Tags: karate

I have a karate test which passes:

```
  Scenario Outline: Find all the the prime factors in the range from <start> to <end> are <result>
    Given path '/primefactors'
    And param start = <start>
    And param end = <end>
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And match header content-type contains 'application/json'
    And match header content-type contains 'charset=utf-8'
    And match response == {numbers:<result>, start:<start>, end:<end>, count:<count>, type:PrimeFactors}
    Examples:
      | start | end | result                                       | count
      | 8     | 10  | {8: [2,2,2], 9:[3,3], 10:[2,5]}              | 3
      | 13    | 16  | {13: [13], 14:[2,7], 15:[3,5], 16:[2,2,2,2]} | 4
```

However, what I would like to do is not have the count variable from the Examples: section and just derive the count from the length of the number of keys in the result object variable this way:

```
 Scenario Outline: Find all the the prime factors in the range from <start> to <end> are <result>
    Given path '/primefactors'
    And param start = <start>
    And param end = <end>
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And match header content-type contains 'application/json'
    And match header content-type contains 'charset=utf-8'
    And def result = <result>
    And match response == {numbers:<result>, start:<start>, end:<end>, count:'#(Object.keys(result).length)', type:PrimeFactors}
    Examples:
      | start | end | result                                        
      | 8     | 10  | {8: [2,2,2], 9:[3,3], 10:[2,5]}               
      | 13    | 16  | {13: [13], 14:[2,7], 15:[3,5], 16:[2,2,2,2]}
```

When I try this I get an error:

```
primefactors.feature:33 - javascript evaluation failed: Object.keys(result).length, TypeError: {8=[2,2,2], 9=[3,3], 10=[2,5]} is not an Object in <eval> at line number 1
```

and the test fails.

Given that `Object.keys(result).length` is valid JS (using Chrome dev console):

```
result = {8: [2,2,2], 9:[3,3], 10:[2,5]} 
{8: Array(3), 9: Array(2), 10: Array(2)}
Object.keys(result).length
3
```

What am I doing wrong?   What is the correct way to do this?

UPDATE (9 April 2019)
The following works successfully:

```
  Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * configure lowerCaseResponseHeaders = true
    * def keys = function(o){ return o.keySet() }
    * def values = function(o){ return o.values() }
    * def size = function(o){ return o.size() }

  Scenario Outline: Find all the the prime factors in the range from <start> to <end> are <result>
    Given path '/primefactors'
    And param start = <start>
    And param end = <end>
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And match header content-type contains 'application/json'
    And match header content-type contains 'charset=utf-8'
    And def result = <result>
    And match response == {numbers:<result>, start:<start>, end:<end>, count: '#(size(result))', type:PrimeFactors}
    Examples:
      | start | end | result
      | 8     | 10  | {8: [2,2,2], 9:[3,3], 10:[2,5]}
      | 13    | 16  | {13: [13], 14:[2,7], 15:[3,5], 16:[2,2,2,2]}
```

Comment: () => doWindmillKick();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the JS in Karate is not really the JS you see in the wild, and this may change when we move to [Graal](https://www.graalvm.org)

Meanwhile please use this trick to get keys, size (and values) from JSON:

```
Scenario: json behaves like a java map within functions
  * def payload = { a: 1, b: 2 }
  * def keys = function(o){ return o.keySet() }
  * def values = function(o){ return o.values() }
  * def size = function(o){ return o.size() }
  * json result = keys(payload)
  * match result == ['a', 'b']
  * json result = values(payload)
  * match result == [1, 2]
  * def length = size(payload)
  * match length == 2
```

You should be able to use a function in embedded expressions, e.g: `'#(keys(foo))'`

In the future we plan to add a `karate.keysOf()` and `karate.sizeOf()` API to make this easier.

Comment: Using your suggestion, I can get the keys and values but I can't seem to get the length of the keys array,

Comment: Yep,  that works.  Thank-you very much.  Solution accepted and I updated the original post with the updated test.